# GoogleAuth.disconnect() on localhost doesn't work proper

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube-api, localhost, disconnect

**my work environment**

- **localhost** with apache2.4
- firefox browser
- windows 10

Here is my console log: 
[firefox console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De6rC.png)
Why am i still logged in after `disconnect()`?
Only after `location.reload()` im logged out...WHY?

**EDIT:
 furthermore:**

1. opened new tab in Firefox , registered myapp with oauth2
2. then i opened new browser tab [myaccount.google.com/permissions](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) and
   removed permission from myapp
3. checked `hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE)`
   tab where myapp is running and still got **true** as return value
4. `location.reload()` in tab where myapp is running
5. checked `hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE)` tab where myapp is running and got **false** as return value

Comment: try to get the return value of `.disconnect()` function and see how it goes

Comment: I think it doesnt help me.
The documentation doesnt mention a return value.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthdisconnect

Ive edited my original post and attached a console log with the return value of the disconnect()

Comment: Most method return a Promise. Could you try to add some delay before console.log

Comment: @Thanh I already did in this console.log. Even if i'm waiting minutes after _disconnect()_ ... still logged in (_hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE)_ returns __true__). Only when page refresh after _disconnect()_ is done  then _hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE)_ returns __false__

Comment: @Thanh ``GoogleAuth.disconnect().then(function (){console.log(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE));})`` return value is _true_ . Also take a look at my EDIT from my topic question

Comment: So it seems that `hasGrantedScopes` only has the info within the current session/browser. Since you removed the permission from another tab/website, some kind of refresh is necessary. Check if Google API gives you any referesh function.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Googles API doesnt really work with "localhost".

I use a service from [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which generates a public URL to my localhost address.
I enabled this generated URL from ngrok in my [google console](https://console.developers.google.com) and now all things works fine.

Shame on google for not mentioning this in there documentation!